# Better way to check if some inputs type file is empty in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that is simple question but I need an advice from experienced people.

I have 3 input type file like:

```
<input type="file" name="1-files" />
<input type="file" name="2-files" />
<input type="file" name="3-files" />
```

I select all inputs (on my page I have also other inputs type file) which name ends with "-files" ( I wrote in Google Chrome console):

```
$("input[type='file'][name*='-files']").length
```

Ok. I select a file using `1-files` input. After that, I run the following code in Google Chrome console:

```
$("input[type='file'][name*='-files']:empty").length
```

I expect to be `2` but appears `3`.

Can you tell me why ?

I want to get all elements of input type file which values are empty. I used in short way the selector `:empty` but it seems not working properly.

Of course, I could use

```
var empty_count = 0;
$.each($("input[type='file'][name*='-files']"), function(k, v){
  if($(this).val() === '')
     empty_count++;
});
```

But I want the shortest way to do this without `$.each`.

Thank you

Comment: Input elements can't contain content, so they're always empty. The [:empty doco](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) says so explicitly...

Comment: You should manage the emptiness with '.val' attribute

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It matches three because `:empty` matches an element with no descendants, and am input element by definition cannot have descendants (so all are empty, and therefore match the `:empty` selector).

To find those elements without selected files, I'd suggest:

```
$("input[type='file'][name*='-files']").filter(function (){
    return !this.value
}).length;
```

References:

- [`:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Okay, then how to count the empty-valued inputs ? without $.each if possible

Comment: No problem, don't worry. I know how difficult is on tablet

Answer (score 3):

you can use `filter` insted of `$.each`..

```
$("input[type='file'][name*='-files']").filter(function(k){
  return $(this).val() === '';
}).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

consider the following codes, i always used this :

```
     $("input[type='file'][name*='-files']").each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
           alert("field is empty");
        }

    });
```

Comment: It's enough `if(!$(this).val().length) alert ...`